# How to erase weight paint of grease pencil?

Tags: weight-painting, grease-pencil

Tried to lower the strength to 0, but it just does not work.
Any ideas? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Hold ctrl or shift while doing it, i think it's control. But make sure you have the strength to .5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strenght of 0.0 means that the brush will have no influence at all. Leave it to 1.0 and set weight (target) to 0.0, then use the brush to erase the weight from the strokes.
Another method is go to edit mode, select all points, go to Grease Pencil Properties, Vertex groups tab, select the vertex group and click "Remove".